# JS function inside a parenthesis with a parenthesis at the end with an argument, what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

What does this code do? Can someone describe why the function is inside a parenthesis and also why it has a parenthesis at the end and what it is doing?

```
 (function (innerKey) {
                //doSomething
 }(key));
```

Comment: The common term is "immediately invoked function expression" or IIFE.

Answer (score 2):

It's a self-invoking anonymous function. It will be called immediately after loading the script, and it will take the element inside the brackets `key` as the function's argument.

You can read more here:
[What is the (function() { } )() construct in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8228281/what-is-the-function-construct-in-javascript)

Comment: what's the difference between the (innnerkey) and (key)? aren't they both arguments?

Comment: Key is the value the outside uses as the parameter for innerkey inside the function. So innerkey is an argument, key isn't. Key is the value used for the argument innerkey. Do note that both innerkey as the function itsself are invisible to the outer scope.

Comment: @CodingMcCodington: Same as the difference between this: `function foo(innerkey) { ... }` and this: `foo(key)`. Remove `foo` in both places, and you have just about the same thing as above.

Comment: @Shilly so key is then converted into innerkey?

Comment: `key` argument can be anything, a string, a number or whatever you want. But if you want to **operate** on it inside the function's body - you will have to use it as `innerKey` variable.

Comment: @squint thanks that made it very clear :), please include answer so I can upvote

Comment: yes. suppose this is a normal function. `function fnName( innerkey ) { ... }` To call that function you would use `fnName( key );` to invoke fnName with the value key, so that key becomes the argument innerkey inside the fn.

Comment: @CodingMcCodington: You're welcome. The question was closed as a duplicate, so we don't really need any more answers. You'll find many more complete descriptions in some of the answers to those questions.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating the function and invoking it at the same time with the key value  filling the innerkey parameter.